# How to parse row results from $wpdb -> get_results

Tags: wpdb

I have the following:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_pod_tbl_add_questions WHERE id LIKE '. $id;

                                        $row = $wpdb -> get_results($query);
```

How do I get the columns named 'id' and 'name' from $row?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE id LIKE' . $id . ';") as $key => $row) {
// each column in your row will be accessible like this
$my_column = $row->column_name;}
```

More info [here](https://www.wphub.com/blog/posts/working-with-database-tables-plugins-part-2/)

Comment: not sure if this is the right way though. I think one should get the result to a variable and use foreach on that, to be safe. E.g. $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql); and then use foreach($results as $value).

Comment: shouldn't really matter in this instance since it returns array, object or null, there shouldn't be any risk of getting a "loop unfriendly" resource. that said you may want to loop through them again for something else, and if so definitely store it. don't query twice

Answer (score 3):

**To use as an associative array:**

```
$obj=[];
$rows =  $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `id` = '.$obj_id , ARRAY_A);
foreach($rows as $row){  $obj=$row; break; }

// $obj is now the selected row if a match was found
```

Usage

```
$something = $obj['column_name'];
foreach($obj as $col => $val)
    echo $col . ': ' . $val . PHP_EOL . '<br />';
```

To get other formats, simply change `ARRAY_A` based on the [documentation for `$wpdb->get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/). Pippin's answer is appropriate for most object use.

**To use one row as an numerically indexed array**

```
$rows =  $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `id` = '.$obj_id , ARRAY_N);
foreach($rows as $row){  $obj=$row; break; }

//Usage
foreach($obj as $col_value) echo $col_value . ' ';
```

**To use one row in an array whose keys are the primary key from your database**(often an `id` column). Possibly more efficient than the associative array method.

```
$rows =  $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `id` = '.$obj_id ,  OBJECT_K);
$obj = $rows[ $obj_id ];

//Usage

$something = $obj->column_name;

//Remember you can loop over objects too
foreach($obj as $col => $val)
    echo $col . ': ' . $val . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 3):

This code work perfect for me:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = "my_table_name";
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM ".$table_name);
    foreach ($myrows as $details) {
      echo $details->id;
      echo $details->name;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always Try the WordPress Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Essentially given the default syntax, the variable $row here is an object containing your results. You could alternately specify the TYPE of result (numeric array, associative array).

Assuming just one result, then $row->id and $row->name should give you the information.

If you get back more than one result, you'd want to loop over the entries in the object.

If you are expecting just one row back, then try using $wpdb->get_row
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row